# Android Volley GET and PUT with cross-copy API

Tags: android, api, http, android-volley

i am trying to use the api of www.cross-copy.net on my app to trasnfer message from my app but i have some problems with API. This is the documentation about www.cross-copy.net

### Service API

The official server is available through http://www.cross-copy.net

#### Basic Usage

waiting for data to appear "on the given secret" (long polling)

```
GET   /api/<secret code>
```

send data in body to all waiting clients

```
PUT   /api/<secret code>
```

parameters

Device

If the parameter device_id=[uuid] is added to the above urls for GET & PUT,  you wont receive the data you send out with the same uuid.

lists data which had been recently sumbitted for a given secret

```
GET   /api/<secret code>/recent-data.json
```

Normally the devices which wants to receive something will start their longpolling GET request *before* data is submitted via PUT to the same secret. But if a client comes late to the party, the recent-data.json ressource provides access to a short history of stuff which has been submitted.

#### Sharing Files

store a file temporary on the server at the given uri

```
POST  /api/<secret code>/<filename.extension>
```

watch number of listeners for changes (long polling)

```
GET   /api/<secret code>?watch=listeners&count=<known num of listeners>
```

Keep on server

By adding the parameter keep_for=[time in seconds] to the PUT url, you can modify the time until the data will be not longer available in recent-data.json

So i have done this class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText message= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="http://www.cross-copy.net/api/nl";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        message.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                message.setText("That didn't work!");
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

When i run application on my editText "message" compare "that didn't work!".

Can you help me?

Comment: Try to debug and read what the error says

Comment: there is not error, the text on editText is that of the onErrorResponse method. So I think I'm wrong in writing the API url

Comment: This method `onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)` is beign called. Check what the variable `error` says

Comment: com.android.volley.TimeoutError
but i repeat i think that the error is in the url that i do GET request, i don't understand how i must to write this url from API guide